# Install Dynamics on prem 365 CE 9.0 on ws 2022 and SQL Server 2022

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-365-ce-onpremises

I am trying to install dynamics 365 9.0 on the following configuration:

- Windows Server 2022
- SQL Server 2022

However, the installation stalls at the verification SQL components step and the download consistently fails. Downloading missing components always fails. [Result scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEF6a.png)

Could you please any information (I cannot found any info about this issue, however configuration seems to be valid according to Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/deploy/software-requirements-for-microsoft-dynamics-365-server?view=op-9-1)

Just relate 1.25 upgrade, but how to install from scratch ?

Thanks.

I tried setup server with multiples official Dynamics 9.0 server and 9.1 KB. First, fail at check. Second, failed because dynamics is not already installed. I've tried to install manually missed component, but some component is not available on manual installation.